# Openshift NodeJS App Deployment Port Error

Tags: node.js, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am using Openshift PaaS service to deploy me Node JS based web application. Everything is executing fine except one. If i am trying to run main node js file (server.js) then it is throwing the "Application 'bloggernodeapp' failed to start (port 8080 not available)" error. Please help me to resolve this issue.

My Server.js file code is following below.

[This is the code of my server.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4OC5.png)

[This is the main error which is occurring when i am trying to execute the server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5db5T.png)

Comment: Please Click on the blue coloured links to get the attached images.

Comment: Please help me guys.

Comment: What has this got to do with AngularJS or Angular Material?

Comment: Sorry. Actually, i am developing this project using Angular and Angular Material. So i have added these tags by mistake.

Comment: No problem. I'lll remove them to avoid confusion.

Comment: Try to force stop your app, then start again.

Comment: Okay. I'll do same.

Answer (score 0):

you check:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || '3000';
var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';

app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, ip);
```

in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
},
"main": "server.js",
```

create file .gitignore

```
node_modules
```

when you use command to start `node server.js` on local and check any errors. if not error then you can devploy to openshift.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Update new server version"
git push
```

done.